# maven: how to packag many modules into a compressed distribution file

Tags: maven-3

I have a mavem pom project with a set of modules under it.

```
parent-pom
     |---child-module-a
     |---child-module-b      
     |---child-module-c
     |---child-module-package
```

In the child-module-package, I want to create a compressed file consisting of files from other child modules.

1. the other module target jars

   files from src/main/resources of other modules and put to "conf" directory in the final compressed jars.

   include dependency jars of other child-modules in the "lib" directory.

   create a manifest file.

Is there a plugin(s) that would allow me to do all the above?
Is the maven-assembly-plugin sufficient to do this?

Comment: You can't create a lib dir in a jar file. You can do such things in a zip/tar.gz archive. The files src/main/resources are already packaged into the resulting jar files of the appropriate modules.

Comment: @khmarbaise - I do want to generate a zip/tar.gz archive. I also need to exclude src/main/resources files from the jar files and package them to zip/tar.gz archive.

Comment: Just move the files from src/main/resources into the package module.